# Total number of values - sum

Tags: sum, factorial

I need to write a program "long int sum(int n)" which sum the total number of values like this:

`1! − 2! + 3! − ... ± n!`

I'm succesful with writing the sum for:

```
1-3 + 5 - ... ± (2n + 1)

float sum (int n) {
int max = 2*n +1, i = 1, sum = 0, ch = 2;

for (i = 1; i <= max; i+2; ){
    if ((ch%2) == 0){
        sum += i;
    }
    else{
        sum = sum - i;
    }
    ch++;
    return sum;
}
```

But I don't know/have an idea how to make it for a factorial sum.

Comment: make a factorial function and call it for every n

Comment: You'll also need to change the loop to run from 1 to n in steps of 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's useful to make another function that does the factorial and one that does the sum of the alternating series . . .

```
    int factorial(int n)
    {
        int sum = 1;
        if (n > 0)
            for (int i = n; i > 1; --i)
                sum *= i;
        else if (n <= 0)
            return 0;

        return sum;
    }

    int alernatingSeriesSum(int nStart)
    {
        if(nStart < 1) return 0;
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i=1; i<nStart; ++i)
            sum += (factorial(i) * ((i%2)==0 ? -1 : 1));  //multiply -1 if its an even #s
        return sum;
    }
```

the factorial is pretty straightforward, multiply by the value, decrement by one and iterate until it reaches 1.

the altnerating series sum is similiar, it calls factorial for reach iterating (except this time the index increases), and creates an alternating sign by mulitplying by -1 every time the index is even. this is how we produce 1! - 2! + 3! - 4! + . . . + (n+1)! - (n+2)!

i hope that helps . . .

if you cannot split it into functions, try writing this all in one main function . . . i tested this code in C and it works. feel free to play with the code and try to read what each line does. good luck.

Comment: what language are u using it in? C# or C++?

Comment: I'm using it... in Ansi C :)

Comment: Please don't provide full code solutions for obvious homework questions. The asker doesn't learn anything (except how to copy and paste code). It's much better to just guide them in the direction they need to go and let them get there on their own.

Answer (score 1):

Split it into two functions. Instead of

```
sum += i;
```

and

```
sum = sum - i;
```

try:

```
sum += factorial(i);
```

and

```
sum = sum - factorial(i)
```

where factorial is some method that computes factorial:

```
long int factorial(int n) {
    long int fact = n;
    while ( n > 1) {
        n--;
        fact *= n;
    }

    return fact;
}
```